# Distinguish modules from packages

Tags: python, module, package

I need a function that returns the name of the *package* of the module from which the function was called. Getting the module's name is easy:

```
import inspect

module_name = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_globals['__name__']
```

And stripping the last part to get the module's package is also easy:

```
package_name = '.'.join(module_name.split('.')[:-1])
```

But if the function is called from a package's `__init__.py`, the last part of the name should not be stripped. E.g. if called from `foo/bar/__init__.py`, `module_name` in the above example will be set to `'foo.bar'`, which is already the name of the package.

How can I check, from the module name or the module object, whether it refers to a package or a module?

The best way I found is getting the module object's `__file__` attribute, if it exists, and check whether it points to a file whose name is `__init__` plus extension. But this seems very brittle to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what `importlib.__import__()` does, which needs to re-implement most of the Python's built-in import logic and needs to find a module's package to support relative imports:

```
# __package__ is not guaranteed to be defined or could be set to None
# to represent that it's proper value is unknown
package = globals.get('__package__')
if package is None:
    package = globals['__name__']
    if '__path__' not in globals:
        package = package.rpartition('.')[0]
module = _gcd_import(name, package, level)
```

So it seems that there is no reliable "direct" way to get a module's package.

Answer (score 1):

from the module object:

```
module.__package__
```

is available for a couple that I looked at, and appears to be correct. it may not give you exactly what you want though:

```
import os.path
import httplib2
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

os.path.__package__
<blank... this is a builtin>
httplib2.__package__
'httplib2'
etree.__package__
'xml.etree'
```

you can use

```
function.__module__
```

also, but that gives you the module name, not the actual module - not sure if there is an easier way to get the module object itself than importing again to a local variable.

```
etree.parse.__module__
'xml.etree.ElementTree'

os.path.split.__module__
'ntpath'
```

The good thing is this appears to be more correct, following the actual location of things, e.g.:

```
httplib2.Response.__module__
'httplib2'
httplib2.copy.copy.__module__
'copy'
httplib2.urlparse.ParseResult.__module__
'urlparse'
```

etc.

Comment: It seems to do what I want. It is documented in [PEP 366](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/), which states that a module may set it's `__package__` attribute to the empty string to disable relative imports. Since I only need it to work for modules under my control, it's not a problem.

Comment: Sorry, your solution didn't work after all. From what I could tell, __package__ is only set on a seemingly random subset of modules, even within the same package. I looked at and posted the algorithm used by `importlib`, which works so far.

Comment: The bold text in my last comment is of course a markup fail, __package__ should be `__package__`.